# How do you add extra data in currentUser object?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to add an extra information that is not in profile for the `currentUser` object in Meteor.  I am thinking it is possible and the technique should be somewhere in `meteor/alanning:roles`.

e.g. if I have a `organizations` object in `users` e.g.

```
{ 
  _id: ...
  profile: { ... }
  roles: [ ... ]
  organizations: [ ... ]
}
```

I would like to see it when I do

```
{{ currentUser }}
```

Comment: You can customize the `users` collection anyway you want, but you have to publish it in order to see the changes from the front-end, _I think_.

Comment: I think so too.  There's a catch-22 I just found with the approach in that my FindFromPublication subscription to users gets destroyed.

Comment: Output of one publication is overwriting another publication you mean?

Answer (score 1):

To push an `orgId` onto the `organizations` array in the user object for example:

```
Meteor.users.update(_id,{$push: {organizations: orgId}});
```

As @Blaze Sahlzen says, you'll need to publish this field:

```
Meteor.publish('orgUsers',function(orgId){
  return Meteor.users.find({organization: orgId},{fields: {organization: 1, profile: 1}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `currentUser` is a global helper in meteor which calls returns `Meteor.user()`

From meteor repo

```
Package.blaze.Blaze.Template.registerHelper('currentUser', function () {
    return Meteor.user();
  });
```

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/2ccb7467c9bb5889a3c36739d2d8b59a0656961c/packages/accounts-base/accounts_client.js#L421

`Meteor.user()` function returns following data

```
user() {
    var userId = this.userId();
    return userId ? this.users.findOne(userId) : null;
  }
```

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L52

Coming to your question, if you want to add extra fields to `currentUser` just publish the data to client.

If you want to publish that field to users by default

```
Meteor.publish(null, function(argument){
  if(this.userId){
    return Members.findOne({userIds: this.userId}, { fields: { organizations: 1,... } });
  }
  this.ready()
});
```